# How to update values in users table of Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

Guys I want to update the rows of users table in Parse.com. So, far I have used user.SignupinBackground method to update password and other fields(added by me other than username and password) but it throws an exception "Cannot sign up a user that has already signed up."

Is there a way to update the data in the rows of users table of parse.

I have already visited [this link](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/Methods_T_Parse_ParseUser.htm) but i didn't found any method for updating the data in the rows of the current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve by this code

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    parseUser.put("columnName", username);
    parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e != null){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }else{
               //updated successfully
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am using the following query but even when the wrong arguement is passed in it i.e. that doesn't exists in the parse users database it still executes the if(e==null) part. The query I used is this  --->>                                            -->>ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("code", getCode);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        // The query was successful.
    } else {
        // Something went wrong.
    }

Comment: if there is no exception means its saved updated data

Comment: but this particular query ""query.whereEqualTo("code", "111");"" is  for checking if a particular value is existing or not then only return the result I guess.  I saw this documentation "" https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#users-querying

Comment: u have to check List<ParseUser> objects not exception here

Comment: it may be possible that your list object get empty with successful query execution

Comment: ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryParseUser = ParseUser.getQuery(); 
        queryParseUser.whereEqualTo("phone",enterdPhone);
        queryParseUser.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
   
   @Override
   public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//    
    if user is not null that means number is already exist into database
    if (user != null) {
     }
    } else {
//     sign up only if number not exist means query result null
    }
   }
  });